# Difference between count(*) and count(1) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In MySql we can count the total number of records by using count(1) or count(*).

Is there any technical difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are the same. This has often been asked in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179969/what-is-better-in-mysql-count-or-count1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124546/sql-best-practice-count1-or-count)

```
count(*), count(0), count(1), count(-1)
```

all return the count.

<del>In fact, in [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1), the expression isn't even evaluated.</del>

**Edit** In fact, in [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1), *a `COUNT(ALL ...)` CONSTANT expression* doesn't appear to be evaluated at all, however, a `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is*.

e.g.

```
select count(ALL 1/0) from xyz; -- Succeeds
```

but

```
select count(DISTINCT 1/0) from xyz;  -- Divide by Zero
```

and at least one exception is `NULL`

```
select count(1) from xyz; -- Operand data type void type is invalid for count operator.
```

FWR in MySQL `count(1/0)` returns 0 irrespective of the number of rows.

Comment: In postgresql `select count(1/0) from xyz` produces a "ERROR:  division by zero" error.

Comment: Yes, is interesting to see how the different RDBMS handle an invalid expression.

Comment: Correct .. `select count(1/0)` returns 0 always.

Comment: COUNT(xxx) return number of rows where xxx is present, you can use COUNT(column) to count number of non-NULL columns ("SELECT count(xxx) FROM table" is conceptually same as "count of rows in 'SELECT xxx FROM table'"). In that light, COUNT(*) being same as COUNT(1) has its logic, as well as 0 returned for COUNT(1/0) in some systems (no record contains 1/0).

Comment: Please note that In SQL Server (at least), when you use SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a) FROM T, the expression is evaluated and is not ignored as mentioned.

Comment: @herby, I am not clear at what you mean by "COUNT(xxx) return number of rows where xxx is present" - This is more the role of WHERE or HAVING isn't it?