# How to UPDATE a column by COUNT of FK from another table?

Tags: mysql, update, subquery, count

How to extend this query for the entire table, to update all `id`s?

```
UPDATE table1 SET number=(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 where id=1
) WHERE id=1
```

`id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` in table1 and `FK` in table2.

How to remove the `WHERE` clause to update each row of table1 by counting the number of rows in table2 with the same `FK` id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an `UPDATE JOIN` of `table1` against a subquery that aggregates `id` counts in `table2`

```
UPDATE
    table1 A INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id,COUNT(1) idcount
    FROM table2 GROUP BY id) B
    USING (id)
SET A.number = B.idcount;
```

This query will not get every `id`. Why? If there is an `id` in `table1` that is missing in `table2`, that does not write a zero in the `numbers` column.

To cover for `id` values missing in `table2`, run this one:

```
UPDATE
    table1 A LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id,COUNT(1) idcount
    FROM table2 GROUP BY id) B
    USING (id)
SET A.number = IFNULL(B.idcount,0);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: is it `COUNT(*)` ?

Comment: I usually use `COUNT(1)`. `COUNT(*)` is fine.

Comment: does it have any advantage? I use `COUNT(*)` as I've read it is faster in `innoDB` comparing with other possibilities including `COUNT(primary_key)`.

Comment: `COUNT(PRIMARY KEY)` is OK as well because a PRIMARY KEY column is required to be `NOT NULL`. `COUNT(1)` lets you forget about worrying about whether a column has a `NULL` or not. There is no real performance gain : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22706/difference-between-count-and-count1-in-mysql